# How to login custom user in django? (UNIQUE)

Tags: python, django, web

I want to login custom user, but it returns an error `{'username': [ValidationError(['A user with that username already exists.'])]}`
. I have a model of `Worker` which inherits from `User` model, but also has some unique fields.

`models.py`

```
class Worker(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.fullname
```

`forms.py`

```
class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Username:', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password:', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password Confirmation:', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password1', 'password2']

class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Username:', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    password = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Password:', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password']
```

`views.py`

```
def registerUser(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('main')
    form = UserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        fullname = request.POST.get('fullname')
        branch_name = request.POST.get('branch')
        branch = Branch.objects.get(name=branch_name)
        position = request.POST.get('position')
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
            user.save()
            worker = Worker.objects.create(user=user, fullname=fullname, branch=branch, position=position)
            worker.save()
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            print(form.errors.as_data())
            return render(request, 'supply/register.html', {'form':form})
    return render(request, 'supply/register.html', {'form':form})

def loginUser(request):
form = UserForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserForm(request.POST)
    fullname = request.POST.get('fullname')
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except:
            print('User does not exist')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            try:
                worker = Worker.objects.get(user=user, fullname=fullname)
                if worker.manager == False:
                    return redirect('main')
                else:
                    return redirect('manager-main')
            except:
                print('No such worker')
                form = UserForm()
                return render(request, 'supply/login.html', {'form':form})
        else:
            print('Username or password does not exist')
    else:
        print(form.errors.as_data())
return render(request, 'supply/login.html', {'form':form})
```

So, I'm trying to login user, and then trying to get worker using `user`. After that, I check if the worker is manager. If he is, I redirect him to a page for managers. If he is not, I redirect him to his page. But if there is no such worker, I render login page again.

But when I'm trying to login, it returns an error: `{'username': [ValidationError(['A user with that username already exists.'])]}`

Is there anyone who knows what is the problem? (No, I didn't find similar question that helped me)

Comment: Please share your UserForm code too.

Comment: Your using a `UserCreationForm` which is used to *create* a NEW user.  Use it for a signup or registration view.  Have a separate login view where you can authenticate and login the user.

Comment: Oh, sounds to be true. Let me fix it

Comment: Yes, now it works. But if now I create new user, it seems to work well, but when then I try to log in, it gives that error. Also in traceback it returns 200 code `[09/Jul/2023 22:34:23] "GET /register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8484`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you doing to login in the user? What do you mean "it returns an error"? What do you do that causes the error? And where do you see the error message?

Comment: So, I check if `form.is_valid`. If not, I print `form.errors.as_data()` in console. Then, if I tried to log the user in, it printed an error: `user with that username alredy exists`. That was happening because I used the same `UserForm`, which used UserCreationForm, in register and login. But actually it is used only to register users. Not to log them in. Then I changed form for logging in. Now it works fine

Comment: I don't mean to be a stickler, but I would suggest that you alter your code to meet PEP8 standards. It's what the Python community decided are the conventions for writing code in Python. You can find a tl;dr of them right here: https://cheatography.com/jmds/cheat-sheets/python-pep8-style-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. These are my final files if anyone finds it useful:

`forms.py`

```
class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Username:', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password:', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password Confirmation:', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password1', 'password2']

class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Username:', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    password = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Password:', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password']
```

`views.py`

```
def loginUser(request):
form = UserLoginForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserLoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username').lower()
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except:
            print('User does not exist')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            worker = Worker.objects.get(user=user)
            if worker.manager == False:
                return redirect('main')
            else:
                return redirect('manager-main')
        else:
            print('Username or password does not exist')
return render(request, 'supply/login.html', {'form':form})

def registerUser(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('main')
    form = UserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        fullname = request.POST.get('fullname')
        branch_name = request.POST.get('branch')
        branch = Branch.objects.get(name=branch_name)
        position = request.POST.get('position')
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.username = user.username.lower()
            user.save()
            login(request, user)
            worker = Worker.objects.create(user=user, fullname=fullname, branch=branch, position=position)
            worker.save()
            return redirect('main')
        else:
            return render(request, 'supply/register.html', {'form':form})
    return render(request, 'supply/register.html', {'form':form})
```

Thanks everyone for your support!